# Is it possible to overload the "evaluation operator"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, evaluation

I am familiar with operator overloading, but a question popped up in my mind.

Is it possible to overload how an object behaves upon evaluating it without any operator? Such as:

```
Object foo;
if(foo){...}
```

So i can overload the evaluation with something like:

```
bool operator evaluation(){
    bool isValid=false;
    //Some instructions and conditions
    return isValid;
}
```

There's probably little to no reason to do something like this, but I'm a bit new to C++ and I'm just exploring all nooks and crannies of it.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean the conversion operation to bool?

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel stupid

Comment: Don't, it's fine to learn ;)

Comment: `Object foo();` is not an object. Will always evaluate to `true` in this context.

Comment: `Object foo;` creates an object.  `Object foo();` declares a function.

Comment: Added a duplicate that explains user defined operator, how to implement them...

Comment: Added more relevant dupes